# Ruby on Rails search like any

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

how could i implement a method that can search those records has any require field which has value `like` any word in the input search keyword.

```rb
module Searchable
  module_function
  def search_like_any(attributes, keyword)
  end
end
```

For example, suppose i have a model `book` that has `name`, `author`, `description` attributes then if i search like this:

```rb
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  include Searchable
end
Book.search_like_any([:name, :author, :description], "ruby on rails")
```

The return result should be books those have either name or author or description contains either "ruby" or "on" or "rails".

Thanks!

Comment: How about splitting the string by space and have array in the second argument or query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

```rb
module Searchable
  module_function
  def search_like_any(attributes, keyword)
    return if attributes.blank? || keyword.blank?
    
    values = keyword.split(/[,?.\s]/).uniq.reject(&:blank?)
    matches = attributes.uniq.product(values).map do |(attr, value)|
     arel_table[attr].matches("%#{value}%")
    end
    where matches.inject(:or)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe help you with this way.

```
def self.search keyword
   word = "%#{keyword}%"
   ("name LIKE ? OR auth LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?",word, word, word)
end
```

Comment: thanks! but your solution incorrect,  i need dynamic pass attributes and keywords, eg. i can search `Person.seach_like_any([:name, :age, :country, :lang, ...], 'Ronaldo Messi Portugal Argentina ...')` and they should match each other, that mean the result should return a Ronaldo who born in Arggentina and a Messi who born in Portugal if them existed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def search_like_any(attributes, keyword)
  query_attrs = attributes.map { |attr| attr.to_s + ' LIKE :search_values'}.join(' OR ')
  Book.where(query_attrs, search_values: keyword)
end
```

Here, `query_attrs` contains the actual query.

Comment: thanks! but your solution is not good enough, i need to search `like` not `=`, could you improve it a little bit ?

Comment: @LamPhan I have replaced `=` with `LIKE` in the answer. It was quite straightforward so you should have guessed that.

Comment: Actually, I missed the `LIKE` part in your question.

Comment: i don't think `sql like` work with an array like that.

Comment: @LamPhan Correct, I have updated the query and removed the splitting of the query string. This should work now.

Comment: Thanks!, but it's not work :D . now your sql `like 'the whole keyword'`, but what i expected is `like %the% or like %whole% or like %keyword%` (each attribute). Check my answer, i learn from Spree open source code.